# Paging Library and Room with different PagedLists that depends of different requests

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am trying to set up all my lists using new Android Architecture Components: [Room Persistance Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html). But I am facing the following problem. Imagine an app that has a lots of diferents lists of the same model. Each list has his own url request to server. Some elements can be repeated in diferent responses. So I think that I have to insert and update all elements of each response to a table of that model. Furthermore, each request has pages. For example, `elements/famous/0`, `elements/famous/1`. So, when page 1 response is received the list containing the elements of list 0 have to add the elements returned by page 1.

A Room request that returns a LivePagedListProvided is like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM elements")
fun getElements(): LivePagedListProvider<Int, Model>
```

When some element of the query changes, or an element added to the database affects de query, the `LivePagedListProvider` observables provide a change, so the UI changes automatically.

The question is: how should I save and retrieve elements that can be contained in differents lists depending on diferent requests using Paging Library?

Comment: Yes, I want to use room to save all elements there

Answer (score 0):

If you use only one table for local storage of your received data (from different requests to the server), so after each updating this table, all your DataSources will be invalidated, so thats why we see autoupdating. For different requests you can use different tables, but this is a not good) 
I think you can write `select query` with some conditions, which represent difference between you requests to the server, if the result model same in those requests.

Comment: The result model is the same. But then I should add a diferent column for each request, which is a not good too. Imagine having requests like: newest items, popular items, awesome items..

Comment: @DamiaFuentes so you can use some sorting for each request (by date, by popular, by awesome), but only if API returns those parameters. If you don't have those parameters you can create three additional tables (newest, popular, awesome) where you can store ids for each element, and after that use this ids in queries to the db.

Comment: Having three tables is not optimal, because number of type queries can increase. I'll do a table with the queries and their responses with the saved ids items in the database.

Comment: @DamiaFuentes guys from google did it in the sample of Room. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/FetchNextSearchPageTask.java

Comment: @DamiaFuentes Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm in search of the same.